# Microsoft mystery MIB or Who has MSFT.MIB

Tags: openssl, snmp

Does anyone have the ASN.1 source for the Microsoft MIB?
I'm not interested in network management but they use their enterprise number to define several object ID's that they include in CSR's generated by the Windows Certificate tool.
Here are some of the OID's I'seen.
From OpenSSL:

```
        Attributes:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.3   :10.0.18363.2
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.20    :unable to print attribute
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.13.2.2   :unable to print attribute
        Requested Extensions:
           
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                E-mail Protection
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10:
                0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

OIDs are only abstract identifiers – they are not tied to SNMP, and they do not necessarily represent things that could be described in an SNMP MIB. (Indeed their usage in X.509 certificates, which are part of ITU-T X.500 directory services, predates SNMP by several years.)

Most X.509 tools such as `openssl` do not support loading external descriptions of attributes or extensions – the parsing of each X.509 extension is done via code, and the list of OIDs and their names is embedded into the program itself.

Microsoft does publish specifications for their CSR extensions in free-form English text:

- [MS-WCCE 3.1.1.4.3.1.1 New Certificate Request Using PKCS #10 Request Format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-wcce/f4eb50d5-62f6-470b-8846-9489af9dea62)
- [Certificate Enrollment API — Supported Attributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccertenroll/supported-attributes)